# working tictactoe grid using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn the flexbox system while making a working tictactoe game. My tictactoe lines get janky when the X's and O's are placed. Is there a way to keep the black line divs (.horizontal and .vertical) from moving around when the player marks the X's and O's? My goal is to achieve a working tictactoe game using the flexbox system (and some minor javascript).

Here's the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ryzw41e1/

HTML:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.row3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.horizontal {
  background-color: black;
  width: 360px;
  height: 12px;
}
.vertical {
  background-color: black;
  width: 12px;
  height: 120px;
}
#cell0 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell4 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell6 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell7 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#cell8 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- my css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylin.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="playerTurn">It is X's turn</h2>
    <div>
      <div class="row1">
        <div id="cell0" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell1" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell2" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div id="cell3" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell4" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell5" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="row3">
        <div id="cell6" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell7" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="cell8" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
  <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First off...don't use `flex-grow:1` You don't want the elements to grow at all...

Comment: Ahaha... the answer was so simple. I can't believe I didn't see it myself. Thanks for your time! I changed them all to flex: 1 and of course they work quite well now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `flex-grow: 1;` which should be `flex: 1;` as @Paulie_D pointed out.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.row2, .row3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.horizontal {
  background-color: black;
  width: 360px;
  height: 12px;
}

.vertical {
  background-color: black;
  width: 12px;
  height: 120px;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="playerTurn">It is X's turn</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="row1">
      <div id="cell0" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell1" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell2" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div id="cell3" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell4" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell5" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div id="cell6" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell7" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="vertical">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="cell8" class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```

This answer was created to remove the question from unanswered.

Comment: flex: 1 changes flex-grow to 1. The one-value flex shorthand syntax is the same as flex: <number> 1 0; the flex-shrink value is assumed to be 1 and the flex-basis value is assumed to be 0.